# When does Angular clear the $watch?

Tags: angularjs

I understand that each model that I include in my view enters the digest loop and `$watch` applied on it, since all Angular applications are basically one page apps. But when does it clear the `$watch`?

For example, let's say that I have the page `view1.html` with the template `{{view.name1}}`. When I switch the route to the page `view2.html` with the template `{{view.name2}}`, does the `$watch` on `{{view.name1}}`  is being unregistered automatically or should I do it manually?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

#### This answer has links to [angular scopes](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/v1.3.2/src/ng/rootScope.js) source code,

Each scope have a private array `$$watchers`:

- When the method `$watch` is called it pushes listeners into `$$watchers`, see [Scope#$watch](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/v1.3.2/src/ng/rootScope.js#L368).
- With each `$digest` it iterates down all the `$$watchers`, see [Scope#$digest](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/v1.3.2/src/ng/rootScope.js#L755).
- When the scope method `$destroy` is called it cleans up all it's watchers, see [Scope#$destroy](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/v1.3.2/src/ng/rootScope.js#L898)
- Each scope also broadcast `$destroy` to all of it's child scopes either isolated or not, so you'll never have an orphan scope.
- Angular listens for DOM node removal and triggers `$destroy` for all directive scopes ( that are created within the $compile service), see [here](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/v1.3.2/src/Angular.js#L1473)

---

#### Angular automatically calls `$destroy` on these cases:

- https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/v1.3.2/src/ng/directive/ngIf.js#L111
- https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/v1.3.2/src/ng/directive/ngInclude.js#L206
- https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/v1.3.2/src/ng/directive/ngRepeat.js#L389
- https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/v1.3.2/src/ng/directive/ngSwitch.js#L160
- https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/v1.3.2/src/ngRoute/directive/ngView.js#L205

---

You'll only need to call `$destroy` when you manually create scopes (`$new` / `$transclude`) and want them to be destroyed before their parent scope.

`ngView` is probably a good example because you have only one element that is bound to it in your application and that element (with it's scope which often is the rootScope) is never destroyed. So angular automatically creates a new child scope(`$new`) when it enters a route and calls `$destroy` on it when exists thus flushing all the watchers which were created by that route.

From [Scope#$new docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope#$new):

> **$destroy()** must be called on a scope when it is desired for the scope
>   and its child scopes to be permanently detached from the parent and
>   thus stop participating in model change detection and listener
>   notification by invoking.

From [$compile - transclusion functions docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$compile#transclusion-functions):

> if you intend to add and remove transcluded content manually in your
>   directive (by calling the transclude function to get the DOM and and
>   calling element.remove() to remove it), then you are also responsible
>   for calling **$destroy** on the transclusion scope.

---

***Take this as a rule, If you manually created a scope (with `$new` or `$transclude`) and it is not needed anymore but it's
parent scope does you need to manually destroy it.***